# Out of memory exception when running multiple test with Android-Espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, gui-testing, ui-testing

I have many test, separated in different files, when I run each class separately it runs fine. But when I run all the tests in my project, I get this error on one of the last test-classes.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17462912 byte allocation with 15698580 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
... 23 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not especially because of `Espresso` itself, though I may be wrong, but more because running all those tests together lead to the creation of some conditions that constraint the available memory. Which isn't a bad thing, because this is what might happen in production.

Looking at your log:

```
// ......
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17462912 byte allocation with 15698580 free bytes and 14MB until OOM

at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
// .....
```

this is a common error when trying to load a large image and there's no sufficient memory to store it.

Usually the solution involves some sort of preprocessing, like scaling down the bitmap before loading it in memory.

I suggest you take this class to get an idea about what is going on when loading large bitmaps, and how to display them efficiently:  https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: You where right, turns out theres a problem with the app, it does not clean up the memory as it is supposed to. Thanks :)

Comment: In debug builds, consider registering a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` which calls `Debug.dumpHprofData` when there's an OOM. May make it easier to debug the next memory leak.